# Activating abilites of enchantments

Tags: magic-the-gathering

As an example, assume I have a [Grizzly Bear](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bGrizzly%20Bear%5d) in play with two enchantments on it: [Dragon Breath](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDragon%20Breath%5d) and [Dizzying Gaze](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDizzying%20Gaze%5d). Both of these enchantments grant my Grizzly Bear an ability that I can activate by paying {R}.

If I pay {R}, do I activate both abilities at once?

Comment: Can you give a specific scenario, with specific cards? It sounds like you may have misunderstood how casing auras on your creatures works, but it's hard to be entirely sure based on what you've written.

Comment: @steenbergh Your edit is definitely one of the possibilities, but the original question referred to *casting* costs of the enchantments, so it's also possible that the OP thought that you had to repay the casting cost of an aura to get its effects.

Comment: @Jefromi That's why I refer to the text of the original question in my answer.

Comment: @steenbergh My point was not so much about your answer but about whether the edited question actually asks what the OP wants. But if anything, referring to the original text in an answer is a bit of a red flag: it suggests that there's something important enough to address that's been removed from the question, and others who don't look at the revision history of every question they answer would miss that.

Comment: If I vote to re-open, will I then be allowed to vote to close as duplicate?

Comment: No, evidently :(

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer: You only activate 1 by paying 1 red mana**

Long answer: let's first clear up your vocabulary a little. From your original question, it's unclear if you want to play both enchantments from your hand onto the Grizzly Bear for {R}, or if you want to use the abilities listed on the enchantments. Do you realise enchantments are what we call 'permanents'? Once played, they remain in play until they are destroyed, returned to your hand or, in the case of creature enchantments, the creature they are bound to disappears. You only pay the casting cost when you put an enchantment in play.

Once the enchantments are in play, they grant additional abilities to the creature they are enchanting. In order to use such an ability, you

- declare you want to use an ability (for instance, the 'deals 1 damage to target creature with flying' ability on [Dizzying Gaze](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDizzying%20Gaze%5d))
- Pay the cost, choose a target
- Resolve the ability (and perhaps others that were placed on the stack as a reaction to this).

As you can see, all of the above is for one of the extra abilities that your creature has, now that it is enchanted. Same goes for the other ability. When you pay {R}, it is always for one activated ability.